# Is a function hoisted if it is defined within an if condition?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

So suppose I have something like this

```
var x = 1;
   if (function f(){}) {
     x += typeof f;
   }
   x;
```

This outputs "1undefined". I thought it should have output "1function", because function f(){} should have been hoisted above the if. This is clearly not the case - why? I thought function declarations and bodies were always hoisted to the top of the scope?

Comment: Actually, it is, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function

Comment: I think this is a named function expression, not a function declaration. The scope of the name is just the body of the function being defined, not the surrounding function.

Comment: It's like `var foo = function f() {};`.

Answer (score 8):

Function declarations are hoisted.  Function expressions [**are not**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting).

This creates a *named* function expression:

```
if(function f(){})
```

It doesn't do anything except check to see if the function expression is truthy. (Function expressions are always truthy.)

Regarding named function expressions, see https://kangax.github.io/nfe/#named-expr:

> An important detail to remember is that this name is **only available in
>   the scope of a newly-defined function**

This code is *outside* the scope of the new function expression, and therefore `f` is undefined:

```
x += typeof f;
```

*Within* a named function expression, you can refer to its name without a problem:

```js
(function f() {
  alert(typeof f);   //function
})();

alert(typeof f);     //undefined
```

Comment: I don't think `toString` is relevant. Functions are object types and are [converted to `true` in boolean contexts](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-if-statement).

Comment: One key thing to understand here is that `function f(){}` by itself is a *function declaration* (which would have been hoisted). But surrounding it with parentheses makes it a *function expression* (which is not hoisted), since that grouping operator (the parentheses) can only contain an expression.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know ES5 does not define the behavior for function declarations inside blocks.

Quoting [Kangax](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#function-declarations-in-blocks):

> FunctionDeclarations are only allowed to appear in Program or
>   FunctionBody. Syntactically, **they can not appear in Block** ({ ... }) —
>   such as that of if, while or for statements. This is because Blocks
>   can only contain Statements, not SourceElements, which
>   FunctionDeclaration is. If we look at production rules carefully, we
>   can see that the only way Expression is allowed directly within Block
>   is when it is part of ExpressionStatement. However,
>   ExpressionStatement is explicitly defined to not begin with "function"
>   keyword, and this is exactly why FunctionDeclaration cannot appear
>   directly within a Statement or Block (note that Block is merely a list
>   of Statements).
>
> Because of these restrictions, **whenever function appears directly in a
>   block (such as in the previous example) it should actually be
>   considered a syntax error**, not function declaration or expression. The
>   problem is that almost none of the implementations I've seen parse
>   these functions strictly per rules (exceptions are BESEN and
>   DMDScript). They interpret them in proprietary ways instead.

Comment: Does `Block` really refer to the `if ( )` part or the `{ body }` part after it?

Comment: I'm almost sure that the `if ( )` itself is considered a block too... but not 100% :(

Comment: since you can declare a variable inside a `for ( )` and its only valid inside its block... I guess it works the same way

Comment: so..why would the above produced 1undefined? (weirdly, I took the example from http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/, which is something kangax wrote)

Comment: If you look at the code before the quote, it looks like I was write. He's talking about `if (foo) { function bar() {...} }`

Comment: Yeah, the function in the OP's code is not in a [block](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-block), which is defined as `{ StatementList }`.

Answer (score 0):

Function declarations are [statements](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-statements). The conditional part of an [if-statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-if-statement) is an expression, so what you have is a function expression; it cannot be a function declaration. And so it isn't hoisted, since only function *declarations* are.