# In appropriate javascript behaviour

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

```js
var y = 1;
if(function f(){}){
  y += typeof f;
}

console.log(y);
```

Can anyone give an answer with an explanation about the above code?

Comment: What would be "appropriate behavior"? What exactly needs explanation?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Is a function hoisted if it is defined within an if condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31664040/is-a-function-hoisted-if-it-is-defined-within-an-if-condition)

Answer (score 2):

Yes this appropriate behavior. The expression `function f(){}` will be converted to boolean. And will return true because function is always truthy.

```js
console.log(Boolean(function f(){}))
```

Now lets come to the second part. Why `y` is `1undefined`. The function `f` is a named function which is only visible in its own function body. You are try to access `f` in the body of `if` so its not accessible there hence it its type is `"undefined"`

```js
console.log(typeof x); //undefined
```

So 1 + "undefined" is equal to "1undfined"(1 will converted to string and added to "undefined")

```js
console.log(1+"undefined")
```

Comment: Just a small nitpick: `f` is `undefined` because the name of a named function expression is visible inside the function only.

Comment: @Teemu _name of a named function expression is visible inside the function only_. I think its not correct. If we declare a named function in global scope its available in all the other function. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @MaheerAli Teemu said "named function *expression*", you're talking about global *declarations*. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/16288046/1048572 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/42456251/1048572

Comment: @Bergi So here the `function x(){}` is named function expession?

Comment: @MaheerAli _"So here the function x(){} is named function expession?"_ - yes it is. Try using `f` after the named function expression inside the `if` statement. You will find that `f` will be undefined.

Comment: @Yousaf Fine I got it thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the function is declared and defined inside the `if` statement which is a block scope and its scope is only valid inside those parentheses. And the if block is getting evaluated because in JavaScript anything inside the `if` condition is coerced to an equivalent truthy or falsy value and for all truth values the `if` loop is executed.

```js
var y = 1;
if (function f() {}) { // f has limited scope i.e within the if parenthesis only
  y += typeof f; //typeof f is "undefined" and 1+undefined gets concatinated as "1undefined"
}

console.log(y);
```

But if you do it like this you will get the desired result:

```js
var y = 1;
let fun=function f(){} //Here the fun has scope outside if statement
if(fun){
  y += typeof fun; //type of fun will be function not undefined
}

console.log(y);
```

Comment: The function is not *declared* at all